# Three way join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables in my database **Sales**, **SalesPeople** and **Appliances**:

**Sales**

```
SaleDate   EmployeeID AppID Qty
---------- ---------- ----- -----------
2010-01-01 1412       150   1
2010-01-05 3231       110   1
2010-01-03 2920       110   2
2010-01-13 1412       100   1
2010-01-25 1235       150   2
2010-01-22 1235       100   2
2010-01-12 2920       150   3
2010-01-14 3231       100   1
2010-01-15 1235       300   1
2010-01-03 2920       200   2
2010-01-31 2920       310   1
2010-01-05 1412       420   1
2010-01-15 3231       400   2
```

**SalesPeople**

```
EmployeeID EmployeeName                   CommRate    BaseSalary  SupervisorID
---------- ------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------
1235       Linda Smith                    15          1200        1412
1412       Anne Green                     12          1800        NULL
2920       Charles Brown                  10          1150        1412
3231       Harry Purple                   18          1700        1412
```

**Appliances**

```
ID   AppType              StoreID Cost          Price
---- -------------------- ------- ------------- -------------
100  Refrigerator         22      150           250
110  Refrigerator         20      175           300
150  Television           27      225           340
200  Microwave Oven       22      120           180
300  Washer               27      200           325
310  Washer               22      280           400
400  Dryer                20      150           220
420  Dryer                22      240           360
```

How can I produce a **ranked** list of salespeople together with their average
commission on sales, **excluding** sales of refrigerators.

The query should display:

```
EmployeeName                   Average Commission
------------------------------ ------------------
Harry Purple                   79.1999969482422
Linda Smith                    75.375
Charles Brown                  59.3333333333333
Anne Green                     42
```

Comment: How do you compute for commission?

Comment: @Felix Commission is generally a percentage of each sale.  I think we can assume the standard definition here.

Comment: What do you mean by ranked list?

Comment: Alex Highest average commisson at top. ie sort by desc on [Average Commisson]

Comment: @WillSmyth . . . I can't figure out what the formula is.  It is not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include all employees -- even those with no sales of Refrigerators -- then use `LEFT JOIN` and put the filter for refrigerators in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT sp.EmployeeName,
       COALESCE(AVG(s.Qty * (sp.CommRate / 100.0) * a.Price), 0) as AvgCommRate
FROM SalesPeople sp LEFT JOIN
     Sales s
     ON s.EmployeeID = sp.EmployeeID LEFT JOIN
     Appliances a
     ON s.AppID = a.ID AND a.AppType <> 'Refrigerator'
GROUP BY sp.EmployeeName
ORDER BY AvgCommRate DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT sp.EmployeeName,
    COALESCE(AVG(s.Qty * (sp.CommRate / 100.0) * a.Price), 0) AS rank
FROM Sales s
LEFT JOIN SalesPeople sp
    ON s.EmployeeID = sp.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN Appliances a
    ON s.AppID = a.ID
WHERE a.AppType <> 'Refrigerator'
GROUP BY sp.EmployeeName
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Your answer is correct, You can multiply by (a.Price) only sorry for the misinformation earlier. No need to minus (a.Cost)